# Post several callbacks as function parameter

Tags: c++, c

I have several functions.

```
void a();
bool b();
void c(int x, int y);
```

An one function whats looks like that.

```
void setListener(void * listenerCallback);
```

I must send all this functions (a, b, c) as parameters of "setListener" functions.

```
setListener(&a);
setListener(&b);
setListener(&c);
```

How can i make this without overloading setListener function?

---

I find one variant. Though I think he may be causing problems with memory. But in fact it is same as in the solve from Lundin, only without union.

```
typedef unsigned int varCallback;

enum callbackType {
    C_VOID,
    C_BOOL,
    C_VOID_INT_INT,
}

void setListener(varCallback callbackPointerAddress, callbackType type) {
    /// code
}

void a() {};
bool b() {};
void c(int x, int y) {};

setListener((varCallback)&a, C_VOID);
setListener((varCallback)&b, C_BOOL);
setListener((varCallback)&c, C_VOID_INT_INT);
```

Comment: Please remember that function pointers don't necessarily have the same size as data pointers.  Also, make sure you use some sort of type code to determine what argument list each function has.  See Lundin's answer, it answers both of the problems at once.

Comment: Are you doing this in C or C++? You will get very, very different answers for each. Note that C does not support function overloading. Also, when designing callbacks you usually enforce a certain function signature (or at least restrict the possibilities). Do you want `setListener()` to accept functions of any arbitrary signature? Or is there only a certain set of function signatures that `setListener()` will accept?

Comment: For what it's worth (now that you have a couple of working answers) I have to say that this design is flawed, prone to errors and counter-intuitive.

Comment: @In silico: `setListener()` actually accept only certain series of callback functions. Also `setListener()` is class method. But I don't whant using templates in code, because I want to add one or more another callback functions function with different arguments and types of return values.

Comment: Since `setListener()` is a class method, I assume you're working in C++ then. In that case, why don't you want to overload the `setListener()` function? That seems to me the easiest way to do it, and you said that it accepts only a certain set of callback functions. Those overloaded functions can properly set values in an `enum` and a `union`. That way, the user code can't screw up and pass in an invalid function.

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged this C, here's a C solution as well (regard as pseudo code):

```
typedef enum
{
  FPTR_VOID_VOID,
  FPTR_BOOL_VOID,
  FPTR_VOID_INT_INT
} Func_ptr_t;

typedef struct
{
  Func_ptr_t type;

  union
  {
    void(*void_void)();
    bool(*bool_void)();
    void(*void_int_int)(int, int);
  };  
} My_func_ptr_t;


My_func_ptr_t var = {FPTR_VOID_VOID, &a};
setListener(&var);
```

EDIT:

(still, regard this as pseudo, I haven't compiled or tested it)

```
void setListener (void * listenerCallback)
{
  const My_func_ptr_t* func_ptr;

  func_ptr = (const My_func_ptr_t*) listenerCallback;

  switch(func_ptr->type)
  {
    case FPTR_VOID_VOID:
    {
      func_ptr->void_void();
      break;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Btw it should be noted that this is the only way to pass several function pointers around generically in C. Wild typecasts from one function pointer to another pointer type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You might want to show how to call the function as well.  It might not be obvious if you've never worked with type codes and unions before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing function template and functor.

Example:

```
void a();
bool b();
void c(int x, int y);

template<typename Fun>
void setListener(Fun listenerCallback);

template<typename Fun, typename TArg1, typename TAgr2, typename R>
struct Functor
{
     Fun   m_fun;
     TArg1 m_arg1;
     TArg2 m_arg2;
     Functor(Fun fun, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2) 
         : m_fun(fun), m_arg1(arg1), m_arg2(arg2) {}
    R operator()()
    {
        return m_fun(arg1, arg2);
    }
};

Functor<void (*)(int,int), int, int, void> c_fun(c, 10, 20);

setListener(&a);
setListener(&b);
setListener(c_fun);
```

`10` and `20` are argument to function `c(int, int)`.

**Note:** this is not very generic solution, this is specific to the problem asked here.

Comment: @André Caron: I think the `a` refers to the `void a()` function in the OP's code snippet.

Comment: @Andre: that is function. See the question first!